# Proxy settings in nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js

I want to use nightwatch with a proxy.
In WebDriver Settings there is an option proxy, so I put:

```
  "webdriver": {
    "start_process": true,
    "proxy": "http://134.119.205.244:8080"
  },
```

but when running my test I get

```
    An error occurred while retrieving a new session
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1142:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:17)
´´´
Any ideas?
```